# Can't get data from related table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two models, Pizza and Topping. Each pizza can have many toppings.

When I try to access each Pizzas toppings it always says the count is 0, despite my mapping table having multiple records.

However, I can get Pizzas which are related to Toppings (which I dont want to do - i guess its the wrong way round for some reason).

**Models:**

```
public class Pizza
{
    public int PizzaId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Topping> PizzaToppings { get; set; }
}

public class Topping
{
    public int ToppingId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Pizza> PizzasOn { get; set; }
}

public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Pizza> Pizzas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Topping> Toppings { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<p>Pizza Topping Count: @Model.PizzaToppings.Count()</p>
```

This returns 0.

**Controller:**

```
public ViewResult ViewPizza(Pizza pizza)
    {
        Pizza pizzaDetails = pizza;

        return View(pizzaDetails);
    }
```

Comment: can you add some code to show how you are accessing this data?

Comment: I've added the view and controller. Another thing, when I dont have a join table made I get the error: Invalid object name 'dbo.ToppingPizzas'. - I would expect this to be 'dbo.PizzaToppings' instead?

Comment: If you place a breakpoint in your controller does the pizza then have any toppings?

Comment: @Peter no, the pizzatoppings is there but there are no values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to explicitly load the Toppings like so:

```
var pizzas = db.Pizzas.Include("PizzaToppings");
var pizza = pizzas.Where()... // select your specific pizza
```

Have a look at this: [Entity Framework - Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896272%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Seeing the entity/model structure it seems lazy loading can be leveraged instead of doing an explicit eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your model in console application it is working fine. Below is my code:

```
        PizzaContext context = new PizzaContext();

        Pizza veggiDelite = new Pizza { Name = "Veggi Delite" };
        Topping pineapple = new Topping { Name = "Pineapple" };
        Topping chicken = new Topping { Name = "Chicken" };
        Pizza supremeChickenPizza = new Pizza { Name = "Supreme Chicken Pizza" };

        veggiDelite.PizzaToppings = new Collection<Topping> { new Topping { Name = "Jalepeeno" }, pineapple };

        supremeChickenPizza.PizzaToppings = new Collection<Topping> { pineapple };

        chicken.PizzasOn = new Collection<Pizza> { supremeChickenPizza };

        context.Pizzas.Add(veggiDelite);

        context.Toppings.Add(chicken);

        context.SaveChanges();

        foreach (Topping topping in context.Pizzas.SelectMany(p => p.PizzaToppings))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(topping.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

[image: Output]

After seeing your code, what I can suggest is to investigate the source from which you are passing the `Pizza object` to your action method. It is possible that the pizza object is loosing the context (for example you are using a web service to get this `Pizza object`) and if that the case then one may face this kind of issue.